How to calculate Euclidean Distance between 2 tensor in Tensor Java 0.5.0
How do i calculate Euclidean Distance between 2 tensor in Tensorflow Java 0.5.0?
This is my code:
public static float[] getFloat(DataBuffer<Float> data) {
        float[] res = new float[(int) data.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            res[i] = data.getObject(i); // Copy each Float element into float[]
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.load("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\TensorflowProject\\Model\\model", "serve")) {
            Graph graph = model.graph();
            try(Session session = model.session()) {
                Ops tf = Ops.create(graph);

                Tensor result = session.runner()
                        .feed("serve_input_layer:0", readImage("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\TensorflowProject\\TrainData\\image.jpg"))
                        .fetch("StatefulPartitionedCall:0").run().get(0);
                DataBuffer<Float> data = result.asRawTensor().data().asFloats();

                Tensor result2 = session.runner()
                        .feed("serve_input_layer:0", readImage("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\TensorflowProject\\TrainData\\image.jpg"))
                        .fetch("StatefulPartitionedCall:0").run().get(0);
                DataBuffer<Float> data2 = result2.asRawTensor().data().asFloats();
                
                Sub<TFloat32> diff = tf.math.sub(tf.constant(getFloat(data)), tf.constant(getFloat(data2)));
                Tensor diffTensor = session.runner().fetch(diff).run().get(0);
                System.out.println("Difference: " + diffTensor.asRawTensor().data().asFloats().getObject(0));
                
                Square<TFloat32> square = tf.math.square(diff);
                Tensor squareTensor = session.runner().fetch(square).run().get(0);
                System.out.println("Square: " + squareTensor.asRawTensor().data().asFloats().getObject(0));
                
                Sqrt<TFloat32> sqrt = tf.math.sqrt(square);
                Tensor distance = session.runner().fetch(sqrt).run().get(0);
                System.out.println("Distance: " + distance.asRawTensor().data().asFloats().getObject(0));
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
    }

This is my output:
Difference: 3.9829087E35
Square: Infinity
Distance: Infinity

Why does this happen? I'm so frustrated, I want to use tf.math because I want to use GPU power instead of CPU power, so please kindly don't ask me to do something like this:
public static double calculateDistance(float[] arr1, float[] arr2) {
        if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both arrays must have the same length.");
        }

        double sum = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            double diff = arr1[i] - arr2[i];
            sum += Math.pow(diff, 2);
        }

        return Math.sqrt(sum);
    }

The above code did work like intended, but as I said i dont want to use CPU power.
this is my pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>tensorflow-core-platform-gpu</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>

Please help me, I've been trying to do this for 2 days but It never worked.
I'm sincerely asking for help please, thank you :)
